# FeathersJS - Sharing/passing data from a before to after hook

Tags: typescript, feathersjs

Using feathersjs in TypeScript I was looking for what is the right way to pass data from before to after hook or to add data to the context.

I tried extending the `HookContext` but then I get `type 'Partial<HooksObject<any>>'` unhappy in app.ts at `app.hooks(appHooks);`

```js
type HookContextWithAssociations = HookContext & { associations: { include: any[] } };

export default () => {
  return function (this: any, context: HookContextWithAssociations) {
    switch (context.type) {
      case 'before':
```